# Reverse proxy with no httpd access

Tags: web-hosting, php, proxy

I'll outline my requirement, proposed solution and if anyone has a better idea please feel free to suggest.

Requirements / Desires - I want multiple clients to be connectible to an address myserver.com:4444 (arbitrary numbers chosen). I wish to then redirect the TCP traffic, invisible to the client, to my VPN. My VPN however randomly assigns a forwarding port so I have no control over what port is assigned, and it changes upon internet disconnection / shutdown etc. In other words, the clients connect to myserver.com:4444 and the server routes the traffic to myhomeip:54321. I would be happy / willing to update this port on the server considering disconnections wouldn't happen to often.

This is essentially saving my friends from reconfiguring their clients (multiple people, out of my control) and making only me reconfigure (one person, my control).

Proposed Solution - Ideally I want it to be free, sorry I'm tight and it's just a small project with friends. As a result I'd be using some free web hosting service - most likely on a shared hosting facility. This means I would not have root access and could NOT access httpd.conf which would usually set up a reverse proxy - typically what I'd be after.

Is there any other coding based solution, given my basic requirements, that can do such a simple port redirect? Again even if it's a hacky solution I'm happy to go in and edit code each time so it works.

My dream come true - A file I could put onto a free web server which has 4 configuration points. Incoming IP, Incoming Port, Outgoing IP, Outgoing Port. Seamlessly routes traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your own Apache server without root access as long as you don't use port below or equal to *1024*. Also you can specify the location of your *httpd.conf* or included files.

However, Nginx would be much easier to setup as [reverse proxy](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html) and you can code with scripting language.